# Why are folders called <photo_name>.JPG.files appearing on my laptop?

Tags: sony-vaio

I've got a new laptop.  When I copy photos to it from my camera I get additional folders with the same file name prefix e.g. DSC01234 and the suffix ".JPG.files".  I get one for each photo.  They each contain files with names like `vcm_s_kf_m160_160x120.jpg` and `vcm_s_kf_repr_832x624.jpg`.  Does anyone have any idea where they're from?  My concern is that it's a virus although NIS 2010 hasn't found anything.

Comment: Says here, if the laptop is a Sony Vaio, the Vaio Content Manager creates those automatically, http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaprograms/thread/e624603a-4eb2-4e84-8303-89c1c8c48447.

Comment: I've +1'd that for you as it is a Vaio and I've found Vaio Content running - yet one more piece of crap on this box.  If you post it as an answer, you'll get the tick (in case you're a points-junkie!).  I'm really disappointed: this is my first Sony and I didn't expect all this pre-installed crap from them - I thought they were better than that.  I won't be paying over the odds again.

Comment: Actually serial, could you post a step-by-step answer of how to fix the issue (you may have to wait 2 days to accept)?  I don't have a Vaio and I only skimmed the link so I wouldn't be able to verify what the solution was.

Comment: It was as harrymc wrote below.  I didn't wait around to see if the content analyser would clean up after itself, I just searched for .JPG.files using Windows Explorer and deleted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thread seems to discuss the same problem:
[When adding pictures to Vista Picture folder it creates a HIDDEN folder of the same name with two copies of same picture in it](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistamedia/thread/89a50671-eca9-4fd5-9c63-1d68eff17e32).

The answer there was:

> Problem is with vaio content analyzer
>   software that comes along with
>   vaio...
>  Just search for the Vaio
>   content analyzer (settings) and
>   unmark
>
> Video analyzis
>  picture
>   analyzis
>  music analyzis

Answer (score 0):

How are you copying the files fro your camera?

If you are using a specific piece of software rather than a straight file copy using Windows explorer then I assume that this software maintains meta-data about the images and/or thumbnails (so it doesn't need to recreate the thumbnail every time it wants to display it) of them in these extra files.

Comment: Nice idea but no, I only use Explorer to copy files.  The SD card goes into the slot on the laptop and I use Explorer.  My phone mini-SD goes into a USB adapter and into a USB socket.  I use Explorer for that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Those subfolders are hidden files, so you need to change the setting in the folder options.
Go to Control Panel > Folder Options > View >
In advance settings, click Don't show hidden files, folders or drives.

This should hide those unwanted subfolders inside My Pictures folder.

Comment: I didn't ask how to get rid of them, I asked what they were.  -1 for not reading the question.  If your approach to fixing problems is to hide them perhaps you should keep your advice to yourself.